# Conditional Formatting Excel Borders

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I have a database that populate from a Macro
In column `B:B` I have dates. The sheet is sorted by Date
My goal is to separate all the blocks of row with the same date by Black line (using borders)
I wrote this code but it does not work correctly

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim n&, i&
n = Cells(150, 2).End(3).Row
For i = n To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i + 1, 2) <> Cells(i , 2) Then Rows(i).Select
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlMedium
End With
Next i
End Sub
```

It is a little bit messy
If someone can help

Comment: can you show an example of desired output? also, please explain what *it does not work correctly* means

Answer (score 1):

You might be better to do this with Conditional Formatting. 
You can only set a thin line or no line using CF, but you can set the default format to a medium line, then make a CF rule to set the border to nothing *except* when your condition is True.  In other words, the CF rule would be False when you want the medium line.